# Ruby: how to know if any ancestor has overridden #initialize to conditionally call `super`

Tags: ruby

I'm coding a series of modules that encapsulate business logic. They are included as mixins in base classes in any number of different combinations.

Each one of this module has it's own `initialize` method defined, because it specifies it's required keyword arguments.

The idea was to call `super` inside these Module's `initialize` method, so arguments would climb up the ancestor chain and reach other module's initialization methods as well.

However, there's a problem with this pattern:

```rb
module SomeModule
  def initialize(arg1: , arg2: , **rest)
    @arg1 = arg1
    @arg2 = arg2
    super
  end
end
```

This achieves the goal of modularity, making so that any class that has this Module will have those two arguments as required, and pass up the ancestor chain for the initialization in other modules. However, the *last* module in the chain will invoke `super`, and that will raise an exception because it's actually reaching `BasicObject`'s #initialize, which takes no arguments.

Even if you use `super if defined?(super)` the same problem arrives, because BasicObject `has` the `super` method (`#initialize`).

I tried using any metaprogramming trick to detect the arity of the super method, but `method(__method__)` will return a `Method` object to the original class (first in the ancestor chain).

So, how to achieve this goal of modularity, making so that included Modules keep calling `#super` in their initialize method up until there are no more modules left, without reaching `BasicObject#initialize` and blowing up, and without having to worry about the order of inclusion of these Modules?

UPDATE: I'd really like to avoid having to rescue the exception to `BasicObject#initialize`.

UPDATE2: calling `super(**rest)` also doesn't cut it, because if any Module in the ancestor chain also depends on an argument that was already absorved by a previous Module, that argument will be missing upstream.

Comment: "*I'm coding a series of modules that encapsulate business logic. They are included as mixins in base classes in any number of different combinations.*" This can get complicated and also scatter business logic all over the code. Consider instead keeping your data objects simple and writing separate classes to manipulate them according to the business logic. Alternatively, make a separate object to store the separate values and use delegation.

Answer (score 2):

You could have your classes inherit from some base class that implements `initialize` accordingly, e.g.:

```
class Base
  def initialize(**)
    super()
  end
end

class MyClass < Base
  include SomeModule
end

MyClass.new(arg1: 'foo', arg2: 'bar')
#=> #<MyClass:0x00007fa394843bb0 @arg1="foo", @arg2="bar">
```

Comment: I like this Stefan; OR make sure that the very first included module (which will be last in the ancestors chain) has this implementation. Thank you.

Comment: @sandre89 since you'd have to always include that 1st module, a base class seems easier to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Answering generically to you question probably would involve a lot of trickery with metaprogramming (if it's possible at all) and this is definitely something that should be avoided, but I'll try to provide an answer to your particular case.

I would recommend to use `prepend` instead of `include`, assuming you are not prepending anything else to these classes that require to have this set of `initialize` methods and catch the final super in the class itself:

```
module M1
  def initialize(arg1:, **kwargs)
    puts "initialize from M1 with arg1 = #{arg1}"
    super
  end
end

module M2
  def initialize(arg2:, **kwargs)
    puts "initialize from M2 with arg1 = #{arg2}"
    super
  end
end

class C1
  prepend M1
  prepend M2

  def initialize(**kwargs)
    puts "initialize from C1"
  end
end

C1.new(arg1: 'A1', arg2: 'A2')
```

In this case you can prepend your modules in the order you want and the final `super` will call `C1#initialize`, so it will be your stopping point in this chain of calls. If you want to call another `super` from `C1#initialize`, just use the variant with arguments and provide just what the next `initialize` expects (it shouldn't know anything about `arg1`, `arg2`, etc.).